# Website tagging: SQLAlchemy inheritance, passing arguments to the superclass, and the many to many relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask

Apologies for the awful title.

I'm setting up a website, using Flask and SQLAlchemy. I'd like a list of tags available for all content types. I'm using sqlite3 for my development database.

After inputting data using the html form, only the tag is not being saved to the db. I'm not sure where the weak point(s?) lies. I can't tell if I've got something wrong conceptually about how SQLAlchemy handles inheritance, passing arguments to a subclass and/or the many to many relationship. I'd really appreciate any clarity on the subject or recommendations about how to improve the model.

Here's the code:

I have an association table for the Many-to-Many relationship between the tags and Content:

```
tagging_association = Table('tagging', Model.metadata,
    Column('content_id', Integer, ForeignKey('content.id')),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)
```

I've set up a Content class:

```
class Content(Model):
    ''' 
    The base class for all content types.
    '''
    __tablename__ = 'content'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = relationship('Tag', secondary='tagging', backref='content')
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = { 
        'polymorphic_identity':'content',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }
```

All content types are subclasses of Content, using SQLAlchemy's Joined Table Inheritance:

```
class Entry(Content):
    '''The database model for blog-like entries on the homepage.'''
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('content.id'), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(200))
    body = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = { 
        'polymorphic_identity':'entries',
    }   

    # Want to pass a single tag first, just to get it to work. Is this how would I do that?
    def __init__(self, title, body, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Entry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
```

And the Tag class:

```
class Tag(Model):
    '''Tag database model.'''
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag = Column(String(30), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, tag):
        self.tag = tag
```

Here's my WTForms class:

```
class EntryForm(Form):
    title = TextField('Title', validators=[Required()])
    body = TextAreaField('Body', validators=[Required()])
    tags = TextField('Tags') 
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Here's where I take the form data and add it to the db:

```
@mod.route('/add_entry/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@requires_admin
def add_entry():
    form = EntryForm()
    if form.validate():
        entry = Entry(form.title(), form.body(), form.tags())
        form.populate_obj(entry)
        db_session.add(entry)
        db_session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('general.index'))
    return render_template('general/add_entry.html', form=form)
```

Comment: please add the code where you take data from the form and add the content with its tags to the DB

Comment: Updated as requested. Thanks for looking @van.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you showed above is the actual code, you can see that your relationship is named `tag` (`tag = relationship(...)`, but in the `EntryForm` your `TextField` property is called `tags`. So your `tag` relationship is never set and therefore never saved. What is set to the field `tags` is just ignored. I assume you just need to rename the `Content.tag` to `Content.tags`.

Above should answer the question why it is not saved, but if you just rename the field, this will not solve your problem. You need to write code that handles your Tags properly:

- when Tag text is assigned to a Content, then you need:

  1. look if the Tag with this `tag` already exists.
  2. if it does, load it.
  3. if it does not, create it
  4. append the found/created tag to the `Content.tags`

See the answer to [Inserting data in Many to Many relationship in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2310548/99594) for similar problem to give you an idea what to do and how it could be done.